# How to use % after LIKE operator in SOQL Rest api

Tags: soql, rest-api

I want to query branches whose name containing a string 'chik'

This query is being used, however getting an error.

```
/services/data/v41.0/query/?q=select+Name+,+Addr__c+,+City__c+,+Ctry__c+,+State_Prov__c+from+Branch__c+where+Name+like+'%"+chik+" '
```

Error:

> Illegal Request
>
> You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.

Comment: More generally speaking, use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to make sure that special characters are encoded correctly.

Answer (score 6):

You need to URL-encode the query string in your URL. '%' is replaced by %25. The URL is invalid because an unescaped % sign is present, but not part of a properly encoded text.